# How to choose committee members strategically?

Tags: phd, thesis-committee

Apparently the original tone of the question offended some people so I have it edited.

My field is highly multidisciplinary and so each of prospective committee members although great experts in their own particular field, may not be greatly familiar with other parts of the project that are outside of their expertise.

1- The project may end up commercially valuable, so I need to protect myself against competition, not necessarily academically but commercially. 
2- A committee since constitutes a great place for discussions of great experts of various field may end up to a point where I could not solely pursue it as the leader and creator of the idea. I want to make it clear that the idea was mine, so it is not hugely disrespectful if I want to be the only person who is in charge of pursuing the idea. 
3- I do want to have great professors on my committee, I want to have the best of the best on my committee. I do not want to compromise the quality of the feedbacks I receive out of being protective of my idea. 
4- I do not want to waste my time on some side project and hide my best ideas out of fear that I may create competition.

How should I choose, and interact with my committee to achieve the above goals strategically? Should I trust that every university professor is absolutely dedicated to helping, mentoring and guiding students? Is that a reasonable assumption, given that there are policies that force students to give up all their rights to any invention and hand it over to university and faculty? Should a student not feel fearful?

Comment: Pick a lion.  http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/faculty/rbrow211/misc/phd.html

Comment: Bob Brown, your comment was actually the answer to my question. Thank you sir.

Comment: I think the downvotes on this question are rather harsh, and the one answer below does not even attempt to answer what I think OP is getting at with their question.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.  I think we need to know what country this is in.  // I suggest you look into patent applications.  Perhaps Law StackExchange could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should begin by saying that my academic field -- pure mathematics -- sounds like it is far away from yours.  On the one hand, it is *not* interdisciplinary; on the other hand, excepting writing books and (a few) other academic materials, I believe that approximately 0% of academics in my field seriously contemplate the commercial applications of their work.  Maybe this gives me a good vantage point to analyze your situation; maybe it means I am wholly unqualified to analyze it.  *Caveat lector*.

Anyway, my reaction to your post is that you are somehow misunderstanding the purpose of a PhD program and PhD thesis.  The goal of a PhD program is to train yourself to the point where you can make a significant, original academic contribution and then to make that contribution.  It has nothing to do with commercial value.  By that I don't mean that it is completely antithetical to commercial value, but rather that it ought to be rather independent of it. A PhD candidate can have commercially viable ideas for sure; in certain circumstances it may even be appropriate to explore or pursue them in parallel to the PhD studies.  But the commercially viable idea should not be the PhD project, because that's not what a PhD project is for.

I admit the possibility that a student has an idea which is a good idea academically and also a good idea commercially -- indeed, that has certainly happened in several cases.  On the one hand though, I suspect that only a small percentage of such "double threat" ideas actually pan out, because (i) it takes double effort to implement something commercially and academically and (ii) the point of a PhD program is to get the increased training and personal research that gives one a better vantage point afterwards than was available before.  In other words, maybe you have a good idea now, but if that idea has a strong academic component, then you will be much better equipped to evaluate the value of your idea *after* having done the conventional work.

As is, I suspect that you do not actually want to do PhD training and write a PhD thesis: the latter especially almost invariably involves close supervision and help from a supervisor, to the extent that the idea and work is probably *not solely your own* when it comes to dividing up potential commercial profits.  Rather, it sounds like you have a commercial idea in mind and are hoping to use your PhD training to implement the idea.  As you yourself recognize: that is just fundamentally awkward bordering on untenable: you are in the program to get the expert help from faculty, but at the same time you are worried about getting too much expert help from faculty.  I think this is fundamentally problematic.

Among the points you raise, perhaps the main one is:

> I do not want to waste my time on some side project and hide my best ideas out of fear that I may create competition.

I think that if you want to do a PhD program at all, you need to be open to intellectual growth in a broader sense.  If you really think that you have your best idea now, before you even begin your PhD work, then a PhD program is not for you.  (If you think: "I have a great idea, and all I need is the technical skill to implement it, but my idea is the innovation and the technical skill is routine."  Well, then I think it is likely that you are wrong.  In technical fields, an unimplementable idea may be worthless.  It may also be worth something, but here's the key point -- without the technical skill of implementation, how do you know the value of your idea?  It is most likely that you cannot evaluate ideas for future promise nearly as well as someone with PhD level training.)

It's not a matter of wasting your time on a side project.  If your idea truly has a worthy academic side, then you can pursue your PhD on the academic side alone, and then you can really develop it.  In my opinion it is very likely that this intellectual development will change your commercial plans, so the "side project" could become more important than the commercial application.  But you will have to give up the highest level of security on your commercial application.  Again, if that is unacceptable to you, maybe you want to start a business and hire these "best of the best" to work for you.

Good luck.

Answer (score 11):

Your question is, in my opinion, written in a tone that is entirely contrary to the spirit of academia.  You might be better off doing some self-study with perhaps a class here and there, and pursuing your business interests.  That way you need not fear getting scooped by any of the university professors dedicated to mentoring, teaching and guiding students.

Comment: A grad student lives on a wage that borders poverty. When he comes up with an invention, he is forced to give up all his rights to the "academic institution". So much for the spirit of academia. I agree that my original tone was not right, but I believe the fear is rational.